# How to I make a form that implements a textfield without having multiple text boxes relating to the same "name"

Tags: html, forms, textbox, textarea

I am currently trying to build a simple form and I want one of the entries to have a large textbox to enter a large amount of data. However in order to do this, it seems I must have two text boxes, like the following:

(This one to initiate the "bigBox")

```
<input type ="text" name = "bigBox">
```

(This one to make the big box)

```
<textarea rows = "4" cols = "50" name = "bigBox"> </textarea>
```

However when I implement the solution like this I am left with two text boxes. How can I remove the initial "input" box but keep the text area one and still allow the user to submit their form as per usual?

Thanks in advance,
Markk1

Comment: "it seems I must have two text boxes" — You don't. What makes you think that?

Comment: just delete the first input - not sure why you need 2

Answer (score -1):

You can consider `textarea` an alias of `input`, so to speak - just that it will be a large area for text not a single row input box. You don't need the first `input` in order to "initiate" the the `textarea` - it is by itself already capable of storing input.